# android-studio JSON ERROR [ java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference]

Tags: json, android-studio

I have a big error..
i don't know why i have that...

my code :

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "https://jordyruiz.herokuapp.com/clubs.json";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_Allclub = "Allclub";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "NomClub";
    private static final String TAG_LIGUE = "Ligue";
    private static final String TAG_DISTRICT = "District";
    private static final String TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE = "NombreEquipe";
    private static final String TAG_CORRESPONDANT = "Correspondant";
    private static final String TAG_ADRESSE = "Adresse";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String TAG_TELEPHONE = "Telephone";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetClubs().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetClubs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clubList;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            clubList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, clubList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_LIGUE,
                    TAG_DISTRICT, TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.Ligue, R.id.district, R.id.nombreequipe});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }


    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseJSON(String json) {
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                // Hashmap for ListView
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clubList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray clubs = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_Allclub);

                // looping through All clubs
                for (int i = 0; i < clubs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = clubs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String ligue = c.getString(TAG_LIGUE);
                    String district = c.getString(TAG_DISTRICT);
                    String nombreequipe = c.getString(TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE);
                    String correspondant = c.getString(TAG_CORRESPONDANT);
                    String adresse = c.getString(TAG_ADRESSE);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String telephone = c.getString(TAG_TELEPHONE);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
                    String urlweb = c.getString(TAG_URL);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                //    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                //    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                //    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);

                    // tmp hashmap for single club
                    HashMap<String, String> club = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    club.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    club.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    club.put(TAG_LIGUE, ligue);
                    club.put(TAG_DISTRICT, district);
                    club.put(TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE, nombreequipe);
                    // adding club to clubs list
                    clubList.add(club);
                }
                return clubList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and my json :

```
{
"Allclub":[{
"id": ​1,
"NomClub": "Alfortville US",
"Ligue": " LIGUE DE PARIS ILE DE FRANCE",
"District": "DISTRICT VAL DE MARNE",
"NombreEquipe": ​23,
"Correspondant": "SAMIR ABDELAZIZ",
"Adresse": "COMPLEXE VAL DE SEINE-Parc Sport, 4 allée Jean Baptiste Preux, - 94140 - ALFORTVILLE",
"Email": "usalfortville@lpiff.fr",
"Telephone": ​148935240,
"Latitude": ​48.7781247,
"Longitude": ​2.42247699999996,
"url": "https://jordyruiz.herokuapp.com/clubs/1.json"},
    {   "id": ​2,
        "NomClub": "PEROU UNI F.C.",
        "Ligue": "LIGUE DE PARIS ILE DE FRANCE",
        "District": "DISTRICT DES HAUTS-DE-SEINE",
        "NombreEquipe": ​1,
        "Correspondant": "CLAVO DIAZ HUGO",
        "Adresse": "2 RUE LOUIS ARMAND - 75015 - PARIS 15",
        "Email": "clavodiaz15@hotmail.com",
        "Telephone": ​672803527,
        "Latitude": ​48.8325026,
        "Longitude": ​2.2759969,
        "url": "https://jordyruiz.herokuapp.com/clubs/2.json"
    }
]}
```

Error Log :

> 12-28 12:36:41.751 32074-32074/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime: Process: org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub, PID: 32074
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:502)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub.MainActivity$GetClubs.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:97)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub.MainActivity$GetClubs.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:50)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   12-28 12:36:46.041 32074-32074/org.esiea.jordy_ruiz_elisabeth_duong.footballclub E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

please can you help me...
thanks

jordy

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON String I would recommand the excellent `JsonReader`.

It's part of an API created by Google, called GSON and is available as of Android 3.0. Should you need to use it on earlier Android version, you may use the standalone JAR file. More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174066/3535408

As for code, this is a short example of a json parser using GSON :

```
private static final String TAG_Allclub = "Allclub";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "NomClub";
    private static final String TAG_LIGUE = "Ligue";
    private static final String TAG_DISTRICT = "District";
    private static final String TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE = "NombreEquipe";
    private static final String TAG_CORRESPONDANT = "Correspondant";
    private static final String TAG_ADRESSE = "Adresse";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String TAG_TELEPHONE = "Telephone";
    private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
    private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";

    public final static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parseClubJson(final String json) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) // checks if string is null or empty
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("json MUST NOT be NULL or EMPTY!");
        try {
            final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(inputStreamReader);

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allClubs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            jsonReader.beginObject(); // if the json starts with a JSON Object
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()){

                // declare the values here, they will be initialized later
                String id;
                String name;
                String ligue;
                String district;
                String nombreequipe;
                String correspondant;
                String adresse;
                String email;
                String telephone;
                String latitude;
                String longitude;
                String urlweb;

                final String node = jsonReader.nextName(); // get the next available JSON node

                if (node.equals(TAG_Allclub)) {// according to your JSON this looks like an array of JSON Object
                    jsonReader.beginArray(); // so we begin a new array
                    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { // while there are nodes inside this array
                        jsonReader.beginObject(); // we know it's an array of json objects

                        final String subNode = jsonReader.nextName();
                        if (subNode.equals(TAG_ID))
                            id = jsonReader.nextString(); // we retrieve the value of this node as a String
                        else if (subNode.equals(TAG_NAME))
                            name = jsonReader.nextString();
                        else if (subNode.equals(TAG_LIGUE))
                            ligue = jsonReader.nextString();
                        // etc -> keep checking for each single possible value
                        // don't forget to add an else in case of an unexpected node ...
                        else
                            jsonReader.skipValue(); // ... that we can safely skip

                        jsonReader.endObject(); //once we are over with this object, we close it
                    }
                    jsonReader.endArray(); // never forget to close the array
                }

                // Once done parsing through current club :
                final HashMap<String, String> currentClub = new HashMap<>();
                // put values here
                allClubs.add(currentClub);
            }
            jsonReader.endObject(); // never forget to close an object

            // Once you are done with parsing the json you can build your return your ArrayList of HasMap here


            // Exception Catching requiered
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { // in case json.getBytes fails
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while parsing JSON - Wrong Encoding! ->\n" + uee.getMessage());
            Log.getStackTraceString(uee);
            return null;
        } catch (final IOException ioe) { // might VERY RARELY occur while reading the current stream.
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while converting from JSON ->\n" + ioe.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` in your `build.gradle` file or use `import android.util.JsonReader`

Note : using `HasMap` is resource expensive and `ArrayList` uses lot's of RAM depending on the number of objects to hold (here `HashMaps`). You'd be better off with POJO so that the end you have something like `Club[]`;

Hope it helped !

Cheers from IN'TECH ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) In " Void doInBackground "clublist= pareJson(jsonStr) doesent work.what I can change in doInBackground ?

2) in " onPostExecute "  it's correct ?

3) for put values its code : "currentClub.put(TAG_ID, id);" ?

4) in " Log.e(TAG,...) doesent work : Error:(165, 19) error: cannot find symbol variable TAG.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://jordyruiz.herokuapp.com/clubs.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_Allclub = "Allclub";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "NomClub";
private static final String TAG_LIGUE = "Ligue";
private static final String TAG_DISTRICT = "District";
private static final String TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE = "NombreEquipe";
private static final String TAG_CORRESPONDANT = "Correspondant";
private static final String TAG_ADRESSE = "Adresse";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String TAG_TELEPHONE = "Telephone";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
private static final String TAG_URL = "url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetClubs().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetClubs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

      //  clubList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, parseClubJson(TAG_ID),
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_LIGUE,
                TAG_DISTRICT, TAG_NOMBREEQUIPE}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.Ligue, R.id.district, R.id.nombreequipe});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
public final static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parseClubJson(final String json) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) // checks if string is null or empty
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("json MUST NOT be NULL or EMPTY!");
    try {
        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(inputStreamReader);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allClubs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        jsonReader.beginObject(); // if the json starts with a JSON Object
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()){

            // declare the values here, they will be initialized later
            String id;
            String name;
            String ligue;
            String district;
            String nombreequipe;
            String correspondant;
            String adresse;
            String email;
            String telephone;
            String latitude;
            String longitude;
            String urlweb;

            final String node = jsonReader.nextName(); // get the next available JSON node

            if (node.equals(TAG_Allclub)) {// according to your JSON this looks like an array of JSON Object
                jsonReader.beginArray(); // so we begin a new array
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { // while there are nodes inside this array
                    jsonReader.beginObject(); // we know it's an array of json objects

                    final String subNode = jsonReader.nextName();
                    if (subNode.equals(TAG_ID))
                        id = jsonReader.nextString(); // we retrieve the value of this node as a String
                    else if (subNode.equals(TAG_NAME))
                        name = jsonReader.nextString();
                    else if (subNode.equals(TAG_LIGUE))
                        ligue = jsonReader.nextString();
                        // etc -> keep checking for each single possible value
                        // don't forget to add an else in case of an unexpected node ...
                    else
                        jsonReader.skipValue(); // ... that we can safely skip

                    jsonReader.endObject(); //once we are over with this object, we close it
                }
                jsonReader.endArray(); // never forget to close the array
            }

            // Once done parsing through current club :
            final HashMap<String, String> currentClub = new HashMap<>();
            // put values here
            currentClub.put(TAG_ID, id);
            currentClub.put(TAG_ID, name);
            currentClub.put(TAG_ID, ligue);
            allClubs.add(currentClub);
        }
        jsonReader.endObject(); // never forget to close an object

        // Once you are done with parsing the json you can build your return your ArrayList of HasMap here

        // Exception Catching requiered
    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { // in case json.getBytes fails
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while parsing JSON - Wrong Encoding! ->\n" + uee.getMessage());
        Log.getStackTraceString(uee);
        return null;
    } catch (final IOException ioe) { // might VERY RARELY occur while reading the current stream.
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while converting from JSON ->\n" + ioe.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}}
```

thanks a lot!

Cheers from ESIEA

jordy

Comment: The `TAG` variable is a code convention in Android. Set in in your current class / Activity. Example : `private final static String TAG = "MainActivity"`, so that when the logger logs, you know from where the message comes. Your JSON Parser is not complete (as I said, I provided a short example). Make sure you check for all possible nodes, so that the parser provide you with the values at the right time, Finally for the `HashMap` it's a key->value pair list. Make sure there is a unique key for a unique value. In your case, `TAG_ID`, one of your keys, is used more than one time.